# How to use iMacros with logic like if/else for instagram?

Tags: javascript, instagram, imacros

I am using iMacros for instagram automation to create an auto-follower. I go to the hashtag section, then go to most recent, and I want to follow anyone in the "most recent section" that I am not already following.

This is what I have:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/p/BRvYjUPjB7m/?tagged=scootershop
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next
```

But i want it to do a sort of "if the button txt is 'follow',  then click it" but if it says 'following', just click "Next".

I am aware iMacros has no built in if/else statement, but I am brand new to this, and need some guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/p/BRvYjUPjB7m/?tagged=scootershop

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next
```